ArcGIS Pro 2.9 Addin popup windows form blocking map display
I have this arcgis pro 2.9 Addin that has its own user interface, winform, that will popup when activate, it will carry out work. But when I pop up another windows form from this Addin UI to interact with the map, for example, to command it to zoom around, I found that the map display becomes less responsive and sometimes becomes blurry, all of these will go away when I close the window form. So, this means the winform.ShowDialog() is kind of blocking the function of the ArcGIS Pro map display. Is there anyway to resolve this? if I use WPF form would that make it better? Please advise.

One needs to put MapView interaction controls inside ArcGIS Pro Addin UI for it to be blocking free.
